# How to store the state of a deeply-nested loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to refactor the following code, as I don't think it is structured well.
Can you think of a more elegant way to do this?

```
Bar::Bar()
{
    m_iter1 = 0; 
    m_iter2 = 0; 
}

bool Bar::foo()
{
    _reinitialize();
    for (; m_iter1 < 2; m_iter1++, m_iter2 = 0) {
        _log("TRYING METHOD: [%d]", m_iter1);
        if (_something_wrong(m_iter1)) {
            return false;
        }
        for (; m_iter2 < 6; m_iter2++) {
            if (_try_with_these_params(m_iter1, m_iter2, ...)) {
                m_status = success;
                // store next iteration in case we need to retry.
                m_iter2++;
                return true;
            } 
        }
    }
    return false;
}

bool try_foo(Bar& bar) 
{
    if (bar.foo()) {
        if (meet_some_criteria) {
            return true;
        } else {
            bar.invalidate();                
            // retry. the Bar object stores the state.
            try_foo(bar);
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

int main()
{
    Bar bar;
    if (try_foo(bar)) {
        _log("SUCCESS");
    } else {
        _log("FAILURE");
    }
}
```

The code loops over different parameter sets and tries to perform some action with these parameters. If the action is successful, then external code may invalidate the action and attempt to retry. The object which performs the action stores the state, so that external code may retry and re-enter the parameter loop at the place it left off.

The output using one parameters affect others, so the calculations need to be accomplished locally within the `Bar` class.

I would like to extend this idea to more dimensions, but doing so with the current design is clumsy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot here depends on how expensive the various actions are.

If initially generating a candidate parameter set is cheap (and the set isn't *too* large), then you might want to just generate all the candidate sets, then give that result to the external code and try each in turn until you find one that the external code will accept.

Comment: Well the actions are less on the expensive side, but the set of parameters may become larger.

Comment: Also, I need to be able to have `Bar` take appropriate actions with the appropriate parameters after the external code decides that the current iteration gives successful results.